# Parse JSON using codable and CodingKeys swift

Tags: json, swift, codable

I tried to solve with many tutorials, but couldn't.

I have JSON structure like this.

```
    {
"Region":[
   {
      "head":[
         {
            "total_count":572888
         },
         {
            "RESULT":{
               "CODE":"000",
               "MESSAGE":"Success."
            }
         },
         {
            "api_version":"1.0"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "row":[
         {
            "COM_NAME":"company",
            "TYPE_CD":null,
            "BIZ_NM":null,
            "TYPE_NM":null,
            "TELNO":"111-1111-1111",
            "MNY_NM":null,
            "POSBL_YN":null,
            "DATE":"2018-09-30",
            "ROAD_ADDR":"adrress",
            "ZIP_CD":"10303",
            "LOGT":"126.80090346",
            "LAT":"37.673069059",
         }
        ]
    }
]

}
```

What I want to do is decode some properties from row section.

So I created some structs like this.

```
struct List: Decodable {
    let Region: [Stores]
}


struct Stores: Decodable {
    let row: [StoreInfo]
}

struct StoreInfo: Decodable {
    let COM_NAME: String?
    let TYPE_NM: String?
    let TELNO: String?
    let DATE: String?
    let ROAD_ADDR: String?
    let LOGT: String?
    let LAT: String?
}
```

And decode with Jsondecoder like this.

```
 let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(List.self, from: data)
 print(decodedData)
```

I get error like this.

```
    keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "Region", intValue: nil),
 Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"Region\", intValue: nil) 
(\"Region\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

How can I decode correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array "Region" contains different types, in swift it would be declared as [Any], so you need to declare row as optional so when the decoder finds and tries to decode the element "head" it will just ignore that element and decode the next one.

```
struct Stores: Decodable {
    let row: [StoreInfo]?
}
```

PS
The error you posted isn't generated from the code posted, the real error for the posted code is

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "row", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "Region", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"row\", intValue: nil) (\"row\").", underlyingError: nil))

DS

Answer (score 0):

I used stores and store info as optional and created struct with Codable and it worked.

```
struct List: Codable {
    let Region: [Stores]?
}


struct Stores: Codable {
    let row: [StoreInfo]?
}

struct StoreInfo: Codable {
    let COM_NAME: String?
    let TYPE_NM: String?
    let TELNO: String?
    let DATE: String?
    let ROAD_ADDR: String?
    let LOGT: String?
    let LAT: String?
}
```